# When can JNI ThrowNew fail?

Tags: c, exception, java-native-interface

From the JNI documentation,

> ```
> jint ThrowNew(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
>     const char *message);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> RETURNS:
>   Returns 0 on success; a negative value on failure.

Under what circumstances would this function fail? Out of stack space, out of heap, etc., would seem to be the usual suspects, but is there any less catastrophic runtime condition that would make this fail? Invalid arguments passed in, sure, but I'd consider those programmer errors.

In other words, would I be justified in asserting the return value of `ThrowNew()`? e.g.

```
jint res = (*env)->ThrowNew(env, clazz, msg);
assert(res == 0);
```

Comment: Note: if NDEBUG is defined, then `assert((*env)->ThrowNew(env, clazz, msg) == 0);` won't ever throw anything! (because the whole `assert` statement does nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EJP observed and demonstrated in his answer, there is a variety of non-catastrophic reasons why `ThrowNew` might fail.

As to your followup question, however:

> In other words, would I be justified in asserting the return value of `ThrowNew()`?

I suppose your idea was that failure of `ThrowNew()` would be unrecoverable anyway, so you need not be concerned about detecting it, except for debugging purposes.  Clearly that is not a safe assumption.

On the other hand, since the express purpose of `ThrowNew()` is to raise an exception in the JNI environment, it is the *unconditional* obligation of the thread that calls that function to avoid subsequently calling any other JNI functions before returning from the native method.  Even if you are not confident that `ThrowNew()` raised any exception, there's not much you can do about it if in fact it didn't.  Since there is anyway little, if any, scope for variation in the thread's behavior following `ThrowNew()`, I don't think it's a problem to `assert()` its return value (without, of course, asserting the whole call).

Answer (score 2):

- Out of memory
- invalid `jclass` value (such as zero)
- no accessible constructor taking a single String argument
- class itself is inaccessible
- class doesn't extend `Throwable`
- ...

Comment: FWIW, I tried a couple of these with 1.8.0_45. If the jclass value is zero, the JVM prints "FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI" and aborts. If the exception class does not have a suitable constructor, a NoSuchMethodError gets thrown instead, and ThrowNew returns 0. If the exception class is not a subclass of Exception, the JVM prints "FATAL ERROR in native method: JNI Throw or ThrowNew received a class argument that is not a Throwable or Throwable subclass" and aborts.

Comment: I would wager that if the constructor throws, including an OOM in Java, that exception will be propagated and ThrowNew will return 0.

Comment: I thought i'd have a read of the JVM source code for ThrowsNew, but i can't find it, so i give up there!

Comment: Postscript: i realised i had -Xcheck:jni on; i tried again without it. jclass zero leads to a segfault in jni_ThrowNew. Missing constructor propagates a NoSuchMethodError as before. An exception class that is not a Throwable gets thrown anyway (!), eventually resulting in 'Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "foo"'.